# apache cxf 3.2.2 not working

Tags: apache, cxf

cxf version used  3.2.2
 All cxf version lib were used in WEB-INF\lib folder
 This is the exception thrown

```
13-Mar-2018 21:38:20.806 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] 
org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup 
Could not start WS-Discovery Service.
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
    at 

 org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.
 startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:259)
    at 
 org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.
 serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.
 startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.
 startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create
 (ServerFactoryBean.java:224)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create
 (JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler$
  SpringServerFactoryBean.create(NamespaceHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

--------------------------apache cxf 3.2.2 version samples code

```
@WebService(name="HelloWorld")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface HelloWorld {
    String sayHi(String text);
    String sayHiToUser(User user);

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerUserMapAdapter.class)
    Map<Integer, User> getUsers();
}
```

------------------i am adding web.xml and cxf-servlet.xml

--------------------------apache-cxf-services.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    
        
            
        
    

-------------------------------------------apache-cxf-services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
  xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xsi:schemaLocation=" 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
  http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" 
        serviceClass="demo.hw.server.HelloWorld" address="/hello_world">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="demo.hw.server.HelloWorldImpl"/>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
    </jaxws:server>
</beans>
```

Comment: jdk used 1.8 tomcat 8.0

Comment: I had used the samples from this site

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws

Comment: i had gone thru this url also. no info   http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html

Comment: i got stuck and i need help .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the real cause is missing in the stacktrace you posted. I've just added a goal to run Tomcat 8 directly from Maven for this https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws sample. You can run it with `mvn cargo:run` to see that it's working.

I wonder why you have added ws-discovery, it's not part of the sample.